# Excel Formula using multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

### Requirement :

Get the point value of one physical Fitness Assessment function considering age and gender variables. Sample parameters below :

[image]

Here's what I have written so far :

```
=(IF(pushup<=22,"0",IF(AND(pushup>=23,pushup<=49),"1",IF(pushup>=50,"2"))))
```

*pushup refers to the cell for the number of pushup input, where should I input gender and age?

Comment: Could you provide the output sample table?

Comment: You should click on the 'tick' mark to choose/show which of the solution solves your issue. This will mark this question as 'answered' in this portal. | If the suggested answer doesn't, please leave a comment sharing the error encountered, or asking that part that u face trouble with (different version maybe).. | It's a nice space to leave complement tq note if u wish too.. (after the tick/upvote of course.. ) /(^_^)

Answer (score 2):

For Excel 2010, you can use this formula for Male:

```
=(G2>=VALUE(LEFT(INDEX($C$3:$D$5,MATCH(F2,$A$3:$A$5,0),1),FIND("-",INDEX($C$3:$D$5,MATCH(F2,$A$3:$A$5,0),1))-1)))+(G2>=INDEX($C$3:$D$5,MATCH(F2,$A$3:$A$5,0),2))
```

where your criteria table is placed in A1, your pushups are placed in G2 and your age is placed in F2.

And this formula for female:

```
=(G9>=VALUE(LEFT(INDEX($C$9:$D$11,MATCH(F9,$A$9:$A$11,0),1),FIND("-",INDEX($C$9:$D$11,MATCH(F9,$A$9:$A$11,0),1))-1)))+(G9>=INDEX($C$9:$D$11,MATCH(F9,$A$9:$A$11,0),2))
```

where your criteria table is placed in A1, your pushups are placed in G9 and your age is placed in F9.  Like this:

[image: result]

First, because you are giving points of 0, 1 and 2 for poor, average and good, you can ignore pushups below the minimum of "Average", so this formula simply does not look at that column of your criteria table.

Second, your formula can be reshaped to give points based on crossing each threshold value. e.g. the logic is:

> 1. If pushups is greater than or equal to 23, give one point.
> 2. If pushups is greater than or equal to 50, give another point.

This allows you to ignore the upper boundary of "Average" so the formula only has to parse out the lower boundary of "Average" using:

```
VALUE(LEFT(INDEX($C$3:$D$5,MATCH(F2,$A$3:$A$5,0),1),FIND("-",INDEX($C$3:$D$5,MATCH(F2,$A$3:$A$5,0),1))-1))
```

The `INDEX($C$3:$D$5,MATCH(F2,$A$3:$A$5,0),1)` selects which row to read in your criteria table using **F2** as the age category by searching in **column A** for F2 and then telling the INDEX to look at that row for criteria which are in **C3:D5**. It then reads the LEFT side up to the "-" and then this is then turned into a number using VALUE.

Because the Good threshold is not text, you do not need all of these gymnastics, so you can do a simple: `+(G2>=INDEX($C$3:$D$5,MATCH(F2,$A$3:$A$5,0),2))` to add the second point.

Lastly, unless you have to stay with your criteria table design you could make it a lot easier by using this:

[image: new approach]

and then your formula becomes this:

```
=SUM(--(H2>=INDEX($C$2:$D$7,MATCH(F2&G2,$A$2:$A$7&$B$2:$B$7,0),{1,2})))
```

Comment: It's good one,,, you are getting 10+ ☺

Comment: Merci - you as well.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm sure that this will help you:*

---

[image]

**How it works:**

- Create a Table like shown above and enter this formula in Column
  **Category**.

  ```
  =IF(AND([@Gender]="M",[@Age]<30),"M30",IF(AND([@Gender]="M",[@Age]>=23,[@Age]<=49),"M49",IF(AND([@Gender]="M",[@Age]>=50),"M50",IF(AND([@Gender]="F",[@Age]<30),"F30",IF(AND([@Gender]="F",[@Age]>=23,[@Age]<=49),"F49",IF(AND([@Gender]="F",[@Age]>=50),"F50",""))))))
  ```

---

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell S36, finish with
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, and fill across, then add new columns **Points** & **Status**.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($S$27:$W$33,SMALL(IF((INDEX($S$27:$W$33,,2)="M"),MATCH(ROW($S$27:$W$33),ROW($S$27:$W$33)),""),ROWS(S36:$S$36)),COLUMNS($A$1:A1)),"")}
  ```
- Formula in cell X36:

  ```
  =(IF(AND($W36="M30",$V36<=22),0,IF(AND($W36="M30",$V36>=23,$V36<=49),1,IF(AND($W36="M30",$V36>=50),2,(IF(AND($W36="M49",$V36<=17),0,IF(AND($W36="M49",$V36>=18,$V36<=40),1,IF(AND($W36="M49",$V36>=27),2,(IF(AND($W36="M50",$V36<=9),0,IF(AND($W36="M50",$V36>=9,$V36<=26),1,IF(AND($W36="M50",$V36>=27),2,""))))))))))))
  ```
- Final formula in cell Y36:

  `=IF($X36=0,"Poor",IF($X36=1,"Average",IF($X36=2,"Good","No data")))`

**N.B.**

- For **female's data** use above shown array (CSE) formula, and remember to replace "M" with "F".
- Then calculate Points & Status using formula shown above.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 2):

1] Create 2 new range names from "Define Name" >>

1. '>> Name : `Male` >> Refers to : `=$B$3:$D$5` >> OK
2. '>> Name : `Female` >> Refers to : `=$B$9:$D$11` >> OK

2] In "Point" `I2`, array (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) formula copied down :

```
=MATCH(H2,INDEX(IFERROR(0+LEFT(INDIRECT(F2,0),FIND("-",INDIRECT(F2,0)&"-")-1),0),MATCH(G2,{0,30,50})))-1
```

3] In "Status" `J2`, formula copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(I2,B$14:B$16,A$14:A$16)
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you have use the Male & Female Named Range,,, and in Formula what is use of `FIND("-",INDIRECT(F2,0)&"-")` since age are not been separated by `-` ?? Formula returns #REF error !!

Comment: e.g. in F2, "Male" which become a named range and refer to B3:D5, the others in the similar case, and ...IFERROR(0+LEFT(INDIRECT(F2,0),FIND("-",INDIRECT(F2,0)&"-")-1),0) is part of formula to return the array of B3:D5 and final return : {0,23,50;0,18,41;0,10,27}

Comment: Using the criteria name create as the range name (Table name) mostly used in multiple tables Lookup.

Comment: ,,, now I got it.. thanks,, is tricky but quite useful,, you are getting +10 ☺